# runtime error 1004 pastespecial method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

Please help
When I use this as Macro...
there is error problem...

```
Sub Working()
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= \_
xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
End If
If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
MsgBox "I'm not empty!"
End If
End Sub
```

the Error code is blow
`If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= \_`

Comment: `If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _` then next line 
`xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
Else
MsgBox "I'm not empty!"
End If`

Comment: Thanks for help.
But the Error still comes...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Working()

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then 
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _ 
     xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True 
Else 
   MsgBox "I'm not empty!"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for help.
I don't know why the "\" came from...
How ever at Excel Macro I am using the same code as you wrote...
But the error still comming...haha

Comment: since your code has no code that copies a value here is how it works: select a cell, then ctrl+c to copy, then select another cell, then run the code above